# Use wordpress with nodejs app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, wordpress, amazon-ec2

My website is running on a node server hosted on amazon ec2 instance.Can I use WordPress now with my website.I am not using PHP anywhere, My website is created using node and angular js.Now I wanted to use WordPress to create a post-form/blog for users. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a Wordpress server with the [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) and then use it as the backend for your site. I use that set up to have Wordpress provide content for an Angular2 site. Although I still use wp-admin for the CMS part.